# npm module error on 'inflight' when attempting to build semantic UI

Tags: npm, react-starter-kit

I'm attempting to use the [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) with SemanticUI on Windows. I can install and build RSK, but when I run `npm install semantic-ui` and go through the set up, I always hit the same module error and I am unsure how to solve it.

```
gulp build
module.js:341
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'inflight'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\glob\glob.js:57:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

I have tried nuking the directory and reinstalling multiple times, but I am unable to get this to work. What is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be hitting the same issues people are having on [npm 2701](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2701). The issue appears to be related to version updates between installing NPM modules (from a quick read over the later parts of the report). Suggestions include running:

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

And alternatively, removing all currently installed node modules *including* globally installed modules (in `/usr/node-modules/` or `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules` for example). The user deleted them manually (i.e. not using `npm`).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue while running react app. I simply installed it

```
npm install inflight
```

Although after it there prompt another error msg which was ***failed to find moudule 'source-list-map'*** then I installed it as well

```
npm install source-list-map
```

I hope it will help you